# Parse Python file and evaluate selected functions

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a file that contains several python functions, each with some statements.

```
def func1():
    codeX...
def func2():
    codeY...
```

codeX and codeY can be multiple statements. I want to be able to parse the file, find a function by name, then evaluate the code in that function.

With the ast module, I can parse the file, find the FunctionDef objects, and get the list of Stmt objects, but how do I turn this into bytecode that I can pass to eval? Should I use the compile module, or the parser module instead?

Basically, the function defs are just used to create separate blocks of code. I want to be able to grab any block of code given the name and then execute that code in eval (providing my own local/global scope objects). If there is a better way to do this than what I described that would be helpful too.

Thanks

Comment: eval takes python code, not byte code. it looks like what you need here might be `exec` instead of `eval`, but either way they take python code.  it sounds like youre pretty much there

Comment: Why? Why not just import the Python file and call the functions?

Comment: @Lennart See my comment to S.Lott below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python 2.6.4:

```
text = """
def fun1():
    print 'fun1'

def fun2():
    print 'fun2'

"""

import ast
tree = ast.parse(text)
# tree.body[0] contains FunctionDef for fun1, tree.body[1] for fun2

wrapped = ast.Interactive(body=[a.body[1]])
code = compile(wrapped, 'yourfile', 'single')
eval(code)
fun2() # prints 'fun2'
```

Take a look at grammar in ast doc: http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar. Top-level statement must be either Module, Interactive or Expression, so you need to wrap function def in one of those.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to grab any block of code given the name and then execute that code ... (providing my own local/global scope objects).

A naive solution looks like this.  This is based on the assumption that the functions don't all depend on global variables.

```
from  file_that_contains_several_python_functions import *
Direction = some_value
func1()
func2()
func3()
```

That *should* do exactly what you want.

However, if all of your functions rely on global variables -- a design that calls to mind 1970's-era FORTRAN -- then you have to do something slightly more complex.

```
 from  file_that_contains_several_python_functions import *
 Direction = some_value
 func1( globals() )
 func2( globals() )
 func3( globals() )
```

And you have to rewrite all of your global-using functions like this.

```
 def func1( context )
     globals().update( context )
     # Now you have access to all kinds of global variables
```

This seems ugly because it is.  Functions which rely entirely on global variables are not really the best idea.

Comment: What if func1() accesses something that is not in the default local scope though? E.g. say func1() accesses a variable called "Direction". "Direction" is not in the local or global scope. It is stored in a data structure in some class. I was going to populate the scope with the data required by the function instead of having the function have to know where that specific piece of data is.

Comment: @Neal: You'd put "Direction=Someclass.somevalue" in this script to "populate the scope with the data" that "is stored in a data structure in some class".

Comment: @S.Lott I guess another thing I was trying to do was eliminate access to anything but what is required. If I call func1() from within a class method, func1() could access the variable self, for example.  I wanted to create a sort of sandboxed scope.

Comment: "func1() could access the variable self"?  How?  "I wanted to create a sort of sandboxed scope."  That's what a script **is**.  If `func1()` depends on other things, compile and `eval()` won't change the dependencies.  Those dependencies are in the body of `func1()`.

Comment: `func1() could access the variable self` I'm pretty sure that's not true

Comment: Sorry you're right about the last point. But your sample code doesn't run for me. func1() can't access Direction

Comment: @Neal: Did you actually include a line that says `Direction=` with an actual value?

Comment: yes. say x.py contains "def f(): print D" and y.py contains "from x import f \n D = "abc" \n  f()". ("\n" not actually in the file...). f cannot see D

Comment: @Neal: Maybe you could pass in `Direction` as an argument to the function?

Comment: @Neal: Sorry.  I had the global vs. module-global variable thing wrong.  I never use global variables under any circumstances.  So I was wrong about how they work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 2.6 or later, then the [`compile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile) function accepts AST objects in addition to source code.

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = ast.parse("print('hello world')")
>>> x = compile(a, "(none)", "exec")
>>> eval(x)
hello world
```

These modules have all been rearranged for Python 3.

Comment: If I use ast.parse, then search for a FuncitonDef object, and pass that object to compile, I get a type error. It seems compile only works with the top-level Module ast object.

Comment: @Neal: you may have to use different mode flags to the `compile()` function, or maybe use `exec` instead of `eval()`. The Python runtime compiler is kind of finicky and requires some experimentation to get it to do what you want it to do.