# How to parse a Python module from file

Tags: python, parsing

I saw [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650110/parse-python-file-and-evaluate-selected-functions) and tried using it by creating a `.py` file with 2 methods and trying to read it.
The file:

```
def f1(a):
    print "hello", a
    return 1

def f2(a,b):
    print "hello",a,", hello",b
```

Trying to read it:

```
>>> r = open('ToParse.py','r')
>>> t = ast.parse(r.read)
```

Exception thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(expr, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

What am I doing wrong?
**My goal** is to get a `python` module and be able to parse it using `Python` - expose its classes and methods.

Comment: Why don't you just import it and then inspect it?

Comment: Python has better introspection mechanisms than most, `dir()`, `inspect`, `__dir__`, etc.  Looks like you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: `r.read` is a method. Surely you meant `r` or `r.read()`?

Comment: I'm not trying to invent the wheel, I'm looking for the best existing wheel :)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, @ cdarke Sometimes we can't import a module, because the dependencies aren't there. But we still want to analyse its structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to expose your classes and methods dynamically, then you probably need to use [eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) along with [compile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile).

In this case you may do it like the following.

Create a file:

```
#test.py
def hello():
    print "hello"
```

And you can call it like this:

```
#main.py
testContent = open("test.py").read()
#evaluate a content
eval(compile(testContent, "<string>", 'exec'))
#call function
hello() #prints hello
```

**EDIT**: there is another way to evaluate file:

```
#main.py
#evaluate a content
eval(compile("import test", "<string>", 'exec')) #test.py
#check list of methods
dir(test) # ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'hello']
#call function
hello() #prints hello
```

*I do realize, that `eval` may be not that good choice, but I don't know other way. I'd glad to see other solution*

Comment: agree. but in some particular cases its usage is suitable

Comment: I just tried it and `PythonWin` didn't recognize my methods. Any chance I can get a list out of `compile()`, of modules and functions (I also need to show them, not just be able to call them)?

Comment: compile and ast.parse are similar in this case. Try with ast.parse directly. Otherwise you can always import the code directly and use dir().

Answer (score 13):

You need to call `read`. So your line

```
t = ast.parse(r.read)
```

Should be

```
t = ast.parse(r.read())
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) for info on files and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse) for info on ast.parse

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
t = ast.parse(r.read()) # () is needed
```

Source: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to parse the function read on the file.

You want

```
t = ast.parse(r.read())
```

or (to more closely follow the example)

```
text = r.read()
ast.parse(text)
```

not

```
t = ast.parse(r.read)
```